# make EditText complete the user's writing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working in android.

I want to have a EditText that has limited options for its input, and also I want it to be able to complete the user's writing for the relevant options.

**for example:**
Lets say the options for the EditText are: **meat, milk, salad, salmon, sweets.**

if I write "m" - it will let me choose between "meat" and "milk".

if I write "s" - it will let me choose between "salad", "sweets" and "salmon" - and when I add "a" (EditText now contains "sa") it will only give me "salad" and "salmon".

Kinda like how the google search Text works.

thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: Use AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: thnaks! it works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with AutoCompleteTextView

```
String[] searchTextarr=new String[]{"meat", "milk", "salad", "salmon", "sweets"};
//Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of language names  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,searchTextarr);  
//Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView  
AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);  
actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character  
actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView  
// actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

use AutoCompleteTextView

```
    String[] searchText=new String[]{"meat", "milk", "salad", "salmon", "sweets"};
    AutoCompleteTextView ac=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.acID);
    ac.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,searchText));
    ac.setThreshold(1);
```